# Assert method call with EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I am writing a unit test around void function.
Inside that I call another function.
I want to test that this function should be called only once.
If it is getting called 0 or 2 times, it should fail.

I have tried using followings.But even if I remove the function call from code, test does not fail.

```
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
EasyMock.expectLastCall().atLeastOnce();
```

Comment: What happens if you tell it to expect two calls to the method?

Comment: Have you called verify() at the end of the test? It's only during verification that EasyMock will check that all expectations have been met.

Comment: @Nizet I did not. After calling verify it is failing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

this should work: (but you could also omit `EasyMock.expectLastCall().once()`)

```
    I m = EasyMock.createMock(I.class);
    m.meth();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
    EasyMock.replay(m);


    m.meth();
    m.meth(); //fails


    EasyMock.verify(m);
```